# Verb tense when comparing two different time frames in a sentence

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-tense

I'm trying to contrast how I'm doing different things in two different times. My sentence is:

"Then and now I (am/was) doing different things."

Which form of "be" is correct in this case? Or are they both wrong?

Comment: I do different things as I did in the past.

Answer (score 1):

"Then and now" usually implies the *same* action or state of being ("I've known him for twenty years and he's kind of a jerk, then and now").  To contrast different ones, you should replace the word "and" with the word ["versus"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/versus):

> "I was doing different things then versus now."

Or separate the "then" part from the "now" part:

> "I am doing different things now than I was then.

In both cases, however, your [verb agreement](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-subject-verb-agreement.html) is determined by whichever time (past or present) comes first.